# PHP multidimensional array counter

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Im trying to make a multidimensional array with two columns. Name and Counter. I can do a single array with all the names. But I dont know how to make it multidimensional and be able to still update the counters. Code i got so far is

```
if (!in_array($prodname, $da)){
    array_push($da, $prodname);
}
```

and then I can dump it back out with a foreach. How do I make it two dimensional? How can I say alright this exists update the old value? etc.

Comment: If you just need name and a counter can't you use a normal array?

Comment: Where are your counters or what are you trying to count?  Fill in the question a little more.

Comment: I am trying to generate a list of inventory and whats in stock. Im doing sql calls to differnt tables and I want to have a list of all the products and out put it in a list like Hammer:1 Screwdriver:5 TapeMeasure:2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need name and counter then you should just be able to use a normal array:

```
$nameCountArray = array();
foreach($names as $name){
    if(!array_key_exists($name,$nameCountArray)){
        $nameCountArray[$name] = 1;
    }else{
        $nameCountArray[$name] = $nameCountArray[$name] + 1;
    }
}
```

If you do need multidimensional arrays these are just arrays of arrays and can be accessed as such. A good example of this is using a 2d array to store locations (say on a 3 by 3 grid):

```
$twoDArray = array(
                  0 => array(0 => 1,
                             1 => 4,
                             2 => 7), 
                  1 => array(0 => 2,
                             1 => 5,
                             2 => 8), 
                  2 => array(0 => 3,
                             1 => 6,
                             2 => 9)
              );

//Grab the item at 1,2
$item = $twoDArray[1][2];//Will give '8'
```

Comment: The first code worked. Is there anyway I can get all the $names that are in the array. Like I can get all the variables by the foreach loop. Can I get the names as well so I can have an output like
    Hammer: 1

Comment: You can loop over the $nameCountArray using `foreach($nameCountArray as $name => $count){` then in your loop you can use $name and $count to print out a message.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want `$da` to look like this:

```
Array(
   "name1" => array("score1" => 80, "score2" => 100),
   "name2" => array("score1" => 50, "score2" => 60),
   "name3" => array("score1" => 90, "score2" => 80),
   ...
)
```

Then all you need to do is something like:

```
function setScore($prodName, $scoreName, $score)
{
    global $da;
    if (!array_key_exists($prodName, $da)) {
        $da[$prodName] = array();
    }
    $da[$prodName][$scoreName] = $score;
}

setScore("name1", "score1", 80);
setScore("name1", "score2", 100);
setScore("name2", "score1", 50);
...
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, which is very possible.

Comment: This will actually work without the `array_key_exists` check.